# reboot reverts back to original

Tags: linux, sysfs

I'm trying to do is simply change the below settings permanently but I am rebooting  however this settings is back to the previous setting!

```
/sys/block/*/queue/rq_affinity  2
/sys/block/*/queue/scheduler        noop
/sys/block/*/queue/nr_requests  256
/sys/block/*/queue/read_ahead_kb    256
```

I've also tried with sudo user and root!

Why is this happening?!

Thanks for any advice or suggestions,

Answer (score 1):

Did you try to set those values, by modyfying those files from run level scripts? i.e. in rc.local add sed command to modify needed values?

Comment: I have added already it into  /etc/rc.local   but no luck

Answer (score 0):

This happens because it exists in memory. You should correctly configure  it according to your distribution.

Comment: I have added already it into /etc/rc.local but no luck